# How to get id data from database deleting - setOnLongClickListener ERROR

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, onlongclicklistener

I have a recyclerview and sql lite database. I keep city names in SQLite database and display them in recyclerview. When the city is setOnclickListener in the recyclerview, the city's weather is shown and I do this by taking the city's id from the sql lite database.

```
arrayList.get(position).id
```

it worked in setOnClickListener but it doesnt work setOnLongClickListener

I want to delete the city name in the recyclerview when I longclick but not deleted becasue it doesnt work.

This error appears in logcat : **" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 "**
or something like that

How can I solve this issue ?

**My Adapter class**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>  {

ArrayList<City> arrayList;
Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db ;
Cursor cursor;
int dbId;



public Adapter(ArrayList<City> arrayList ,Context context ){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;

    db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("City",MODE_PRIVATE,null);


}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerviewRowBinding recyclerviewRowBinding = 
    RecyclerviewRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
    parent,
    false);
    return new MyViewHolder(recyclerviewRowBinding);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.binding.MytxtCities.setText(arrayList.get(position).cityName);


    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warningicon);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure that you want to delete "+arrayList.get(position).cityName);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, which) -> {

                arrayList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,arrayList.size());

                dbId = arrayList.get(position).id; // <---the error is in this code
                System.out.println("dbId"+dbId);

                //db.execSQL("DELETE FROM city WHERE id ='" + arrayList.get(position).id + "'");


                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM city WHERE id=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(dbId)});
                Result(cursor);



            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {

                //doing nothing
            }).show();


            return true;
        }


    });


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("citId",arrayList.get(position).id); // <-- it works very well here and sends with intent
        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    });
}


private void Result(Cursor cursor){

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){

        db.delete("city","id=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(dbId)});
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"something went wrong !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}



public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Mytxt_cities;
    private RecyclerviewRowBinding binding;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerviewRowBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
        Mytxt_cities = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Mytxt_cities);



    }


 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have in your code

```
arrayList.remove(position);
```

then few lines below

```
dbId = arrayList.get(position).id; // <---the error is in this code
```

your array list is empty after `remove` call, but you are still trying to get this item at `position`, thus you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` - you are trying to obtain item at `position = 0` and array is empty

try to move obtaining `dbId` BEFORE removing from array

```
            dbId = arrayList.get(position).id;
            arrayList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            //notifyItemRangeChanged(position,arrayList.size()); // this line is unnecessary
```

Comment: Thank you. Very logical. I solved this issue as you said. I did it like this                                      
 1 - dbId = arrayList.get(position).id;  
  2- arrayList.remove(position);